# Mount ZFS dataset in unprivileged container

Tags: mount, lxc, zfsonlinux

First a bit of information about my configuration:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- ZFS pool created
- LXC containers stored in pool/lxc
- Dataset created in `pool/mydataset` owned by `user1`

Now I need one of the containers to access the files/folders in `pool/mydataset`. I tried the following:

- Created a user `user1` inside the container
- Edited `pool/lxc/mycontainer/config` and added:

  ```
  lxc.mount.entry = /pool/mydataset mnt/mydataset none rw,bind 0 0
  ```

When I start the container the dataset is mounted, but `ls -la /mnt/mydataset` in the container shows `nobody:nogroup` instead of `user1:user1`, which means all files are read-only.

Any idea how to get the correct permissions in the mounted directory?

Comment: I've never been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same. The reason, in my case, is that the filesystem to be bind-mounted is owned by UID:GID **in the range of the host machine**.

An unprivileged container, by definition, uses UIDs outside the normal range, and a user namespace to give the appearance of normality in the container.

[image: A <code>ps -efH</code> screenshot in my host machine.]

Note that everything below the container's `init` belongs to numeric UID 1000000, as seen from the host machine. *Within the container*, PID1 is UID root, as expected.

What does that mean? If, in the host machine, you have a filesystem owned by a normal user (maybe root, maybe regular user), and then bind-mount it in the container, the UIDs (which are stored as integers) **make no sense within the container**.

Further, because the UIDs the container sees don't even belong to its user namespace, **not even root inside the container can `chown` those files**.

*Solution:* In the host machine, `chown` the files so that they belong to root inside the container. In my case, as pictured above, I had to:

- Mount `tank/mydataset` at `/tank/mydataset` in the host machine
- `chown 1000000:1000000 /tank/mydataset`
- (In the container config file) `lxc.mount.entry = /tank/mydataset path/in/container/ none bind 0 0`